# How to type the return value in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm able to tipe the argument's type but not what it's returned.
I can see the return is either string or undefined but for some reason my interface is not accepted for:

> reEmail.test(value)

`value` gives me the following error: `Argument of type 'ValidatorsProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

```js
interface ValidatorsProps {
  (value: string | number): string | undefined 
}
```

```js
export const mustBeEmail = (value: ValidatorsProps) => {
  const reEmail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return reEmail.test(value) ? undefined : "Email format is not correct";
};
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` has interface type and not compatible with string.
Possible solution is

```
export const mustBeEmail = (value: ValidatorsProps) => {
    const reEmail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var res = value('some argument');
    if (res !== undefined)
        return reEmail.test(res) ? undefined : "Email format is not correct";
    else
        // return something else
};
```

You should call your `value` to get result, check it for possible `undefined` and pass to `test`